# Getting a Dynamically generated ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox where the values are dynamically populated from the data on my database. I would like to perform further queries based on the clicked checkbox, however I cant seem to retrieve the ID whenever I click on any of the checkboxes. I do not want to use a submit button. How can this be achieved??

My code.

```
function getDBlist() {
            global $link;
            $qry = ("SHOW DATABASES");
            $res = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry );
            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $res ) ) {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="db" id="' . $row ['Database'] . '"   value="' . $row ['Database'] . '" />';
                echo $row ['Database'];
            }
        }
        getDBlist ();
```

My Script

```
$(document).on("change","checkbox", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var id = this.id;
    alert(val, id);
});
```

When I click on any of the checkboxes I don't get an alert with either the value or the ID. What am I doing wrong here? Could it be because of my dynamically generated ID?

Comment: Replace this line var id = this.id; with var id = val.id;

Comment: `$(".checkbox")` selects any element with `class="checkbox"`...
To select the `checkbox` **element** use `$("input[type='checkbox']")` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind change event to the dynamically generated checkboxes you need to delegate `change` event like below

```
$(document).on("change",".checkbox", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var id = this.id;
    alert(val, id);
});
```

Above code will work for both existing and dynamically created checkboxes. Here `document` object will delgate change event to checkboxes with `class="checkbox"`

Also as mentioned by @Ghost, you need to add class to dynamically generated checkboxes like below

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" 
             name="db" id="' . $row ['Database'] . '"   
             value="' . $row ['Database'] . '" 
             class="checkbox"/>';
```

**[More Information for .on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: have you added class attribute to the dynamically generated checkbox as shown in my edited post

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and examples.

Comment: Hey, how can I post the ID or IDs (multiple options are selected) so I can run queries based on these selections? If I use `windows.location.assign` it refreshes the page per click. I have tried this  `$.post("index.php", {
        id: this.id,
        checked: this.checked
    });`
Then using `$_POST` in my php function to retrieve the ID but I get nothing, any suggestions?

Comment: try this `$.post("index.php", $('.checkbox:checked').attr('id'));`

Comment: I just tried that with the following function in my php  `showTables() {
                if (isset ( $_POST ['id'] )) {
                        $id = $_POST ['id'];
                        echo $id;
                }else {
                echo "No ID Found";
}
        }`
But I get 'No ID Found' even after I select a checkbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73575/discussion-between-noobatnerd-and-bhushan-kawadkar).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your echo statement rendering the markup, you haven't designated `class="checkbox"` at all:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="db" id="' . $row ['Database'] . '"   value="' . $row ['Database'] . '" />';
```

Since you haven't added it, pointing to `$(".checkbox")` won't work. You need to add them in the echo.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery selector is looking for an element with the css class `checkbox', either add this class to your html:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"...';
```

Or remove the period in the selector, to target all checkbox elements:

```
$("checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var id = this.id;
    alert(val, id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("body").on("change",".checkbox", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(val, id);
});
```